# Incrementing numbers starting from 0000

Tags: javascript

I have a starting number to work from which is 0000 and increment it by one, i have that done, but the result is 1,2,3 instead of 0001,0002,0003 etc. How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `n` be the number. Then use the [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method as follows:

```
var output = [], n, padded;
for (n=0; n<=9999; n++) {
    padded = ('000'+n).slice(-4); // Prefix three zeros, and get the last 4 chars
    output.push(padded);
}
console.log(output); // ["0000", "0001", ..., "9999"]
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qJSBg/

Comment: Nice one, I used to do that as `("0000").substr(0, 4-nStr.length)+nStr;`, but slice fits better here.

Comment: Nice to see but...as JavaScript beginner, it looks so complicated for a simple task!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
         for (let k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
          for (let l = 0; l <= 9; l++) {

           let yournumber = i.toString() + j.toString() + k.toString() + l.toString();
            console.log(yournumber);

          }
       }
   }
}
```